# How to convert a >2 column dataframe to 2 columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having problems transforming my data.

I have a dataframe, which tells which transitions were made, and how many times this sequence of transitions has occured. The different columns are corresponding with the situation in period 10, 11 and 12 (and there are more in my data). I want to summarize this data, and want to know how many times people went from A to C, A to D, but also C to G, etc. So basically I want to aggregate this data based on each column with the second column. My ultimate goal is to turn this data into a sankey diagram.

To illustrate:

```
df<-data.frame(s10=unlist(strsplit("AAAABBBBBC","")),
           s11=unlist(strsplit("CCDDEEFFFF","")),
           s12=unlist(strsplit("GHIGJKMNNN","")),
           freq=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70, 40, 20, 20))
   s10 s11 s12 freq
1    A   C   G   10
2    A   C   H   20
3    A   D   I   30
4    A   D   G   40
5    B   E   J   50
6    B   E   K   60
7    B   F   M   70
8    B   F   N   40
9    B   F   N   20
10   C   F   N   20
```

And I aim to get this result:

```
     colA  colB     freq    
1    A     C        30
2    A     D        70
3    B     E        110
4    B     F        130
5    C     F        20
6    C     G        10
7    C     H        20
8    D     G        40
9    D     I        30
10   E     J        50
11   E     K        60
12   F     M        70
13   F     N        80
```

I got this result by first aggregating the sum of frequencies for s10 and s11, and for s11 and s12, and then changing the column names and binding them together. It works for, but I intend to do this with more columns, so I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this. See the code I used below:

```
bl1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(s10, s11) %>% 
  summarise(freq = sum(freq)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
bl2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(s11, s12) %>% 
  summarise(freq = sum(freq)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
colnames(bl1) <- c('colA', 'colB','freq' )
colnames(bl2) <- c('colA', 'colB','freq' )
rbind(bl1, bl2)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `rbind` the selected columns of the data.frames together and then use `aggregate`. The only trick is to rename the columns so that they match. For this, I use `setNames`.

```
aggregate(freq ~ colA + colB,
          data=rbind(setNames(df[c("s10", "s11", "freq")], c("colA", "colB", "freq")),
                     setNames(df[c("s11", "s12", "freq")], c("colA", "colB", "freq"))),
          FUN=sum)
```

this returns the desired result.

```
   colA colB freq
1     A    C   30
2     A    D   70
3     B    E  110
4     B    F  130
5     C    F   20
6     C    G   10
7     D    G   40
8     C    H   20
9     D    I   30
10    E    J   50
11    E    K   60
12    F    M   70
13    F    N   80
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. I gave it a go and had some fun with benchmarking.  An alternate aproach (that I used) was to use `aggregate()` itself. See fun1 for implementation. I have made it to fit this particular example, and of course it will need tweaking to work with data frames of other widths

`Edit: I have removed dataframe creation from functions and added Benchmarking output1`

```
require(dplyr); require(microbenchmark)


df<-data.frame(s10=unlist(strsplit("AAAABBBBBC","")),
               s11=unlist(strsplit("CCDDEEFFFF","")),
               s12=unlist(strsplit("GHIGJKMNNN","")),
               freq=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70, 40, 20, 20))

fun0<- function(){

  bl1 <- df %>% 
    group_by(s10, s11) %>% 
    summarise(freq = sum(freq)) %>%
    as.data.frame()
    bl2 <- df %>% 
    group_by(s11, s12) %>% 
    summarise(freq = sum(freq)) %>%
    as.data.frame()
    colnames(bl1) <- c('colA', 'colB','freq' )
    colnames(bl2) <- c('colA', 'colB','freq' )

    return(rbind(bl1, bl2))

}


fun1<- function(){

  a<- apply(df[,c(1,2)], 1, function(x)paste(x[1],x[2], sep="",collapse = "" ))
  b<- apply(df[,c(2,3)], 1, function(x)paste(x[1],x[2], sep="",collapse = "" ))
  z<-data.frame(x=c(a,b),f=rep(df$freq,2))

  return( aggregate(  f~x ,  data=z, FUN=sum) )

}

fun0()
fun1()

#benchmarking 


MB_res <- microbenchmark( fun0=fun0(), fun1=fun1() , times=1000)
MB_res
```

Results were:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 fun0 2.218889 2.587820 2.773454 2.676921 2.785586 6.020277  1000
 fun1 1.472971 1.737751 1.908966 1.842152 1.910118 8.915407  1000
```